# Is it possible to map a texture to quads similar to OpenGL with just Graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, 2.5d

I am creating a skyline game as a side project for fun, and I was having trouble when I would get to texturing the walls of the buildings, I currently am just drawing a polygon to that area, but I want to know if there is a way to texture it such that a texture like this:

[image: Square]

could be rendered like this:

[image: Square mapped to parallelogram]

Here is an image of the game, and the parts I want to texture are the gray walls of the buildings.

[image: Gameplay image]

I know I can do this by creating a separate rendering system that draws it pixel by pixel, but I am trying to avoid that.

My specific question is if there exists methods in Java's Graphics or something similar that can accomplish this.

Comment: Maybe [AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) is what you need?

Comment: @msandiford that looks promising, but I don't think it has texturing capabilities

Comment: What you are describing with the illustration is doable with AffineTransform (it supports texturing), but the screenshot shows perspective projection and that is not supported by affine transformation.

Comment: @msell I am not using any projections in this, it is strictly 2.5D, each of the faces of the building is an individual polygon being rendered, could you please direct me to a link that explains how to do texturing with AffineTransform, I have never used it before. Thanks!

Comment: I think there are a bunch of ways you could use this, but maybe the most direct would be to use [Graphics2D#drawImage(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-).  Bit hard to know what the best approach would be without seeing some code.

Comment: Yes you are. The roof of the building is bigger than the bottom. The drawable size depends on the distance to the camera making it a perspective projection. Also the offset to the center of the screen affects the visible size of the quad. If you'd use e.g. isometric projection, you could use Graphics2D with AffineTransform.

Comment: @msell I did my own calculations for those, and I'm trying to get Affine to work with it rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to perform a shear transformation [AffineTransformation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#shear%28double,%20double%29) is your solution.

```
AffineTransform at;

double shx, shy;
at.shear(shx, shy);
```

use the AffineTransformation when draw image - sadly it's not so obvious that you have to use Graphics2D for that purpose

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    BufferedImage img = ...;
    AffineTransform at = ...;
    g2d.drawImage(img, at, null);//null-param is the ImageObserver
    ....
}
```